# How to get Canvas draw arc touch listener? (Android)

Tags: android, android-custom-view

How to get canvas arc touch listener.

I am creating a pie chart with dynamic arcs. I need to perform some task when the arc is clicked (for that I need to know which arch was clicked).

onTouchEvent of View just gives event from which we can get the x & y coordinated but here the arc has thickness.

How can I get the click listener for each arc?

NOTE - Please don't suggest any library

Need to create this kind of pie chart
https://camo.githubusercontent.com/7e8a4a3c938c21d032d44d999edd781b6e146f2a/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f5068696c4a61792f4d50416e64726f696443686172742f6d61737465722f73637265656e73686f74732f73696d706c6564657369676e5f7069656368617274312e706e67

**My current implementation**

```
private lateinit var mRectF: RectF
    private lateinit var mRectFInner: RectF
    private lateinit var mPaint: Paint

    private lateinit var mCanvas: Canvas
    private var isTouched = false
    private lateinit var mBitmap:Bitmap

    private var pieChartItemList = arrayListOf<PieChartItem>()
    private var innerOuterCircleGap: Float = 0F

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(null)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        init(attrs)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        init(attrs)
    }

    private fun init(@Nullable set: AttributeSet?) {
        mPaint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
        var typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(set, R.styleable.MyCustomView)
        innerOuterCircleGap = typedArray.getFloat(R.styleable.MyCustomView_innerOuterCircleGap, 0F)
    }

    //onDraw is called several times - so don't
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        drawPieChart(canvas)
    }

    private fun drawPieChart(canvas: Canvas?) {
        var unselectedConstant = 10
        mPaint.color = Color.BLACK
        canvas?.drawRect(0F, 0F, width.toFloat() - unselectedConstant, width.toFloat() - unselectedConstant, mPaint)
        mRectF = RectF(0F, 0F, width.toFloat() - unselectedConstant, height.toFloat() - unselectedConstant)
        mRectFInner = RectF(innerOuterCircleGap, innerOuterCircleGap, width.toFloat() - innerOuterCircleGap - unselectedConstant,
                height.toFloat() - innerOuterCircleGap - unselectedConstant)

        var startAngle = 0F
        var sweepAngle: Float
        var radius: Float = width.toFloat() / 2
        Log.e("ANKUSH", "width = $width height = $height radius = $radius")
        for (i in 0 until pieChartItemList.size) {
            sweepAngle = (pieChartItemList[i].percent * 3.6).toFloat()
            Log.e("ANKUSH - SweepAngle $i", sweepAngle.toString())
            mPaint.color = pieChartItemList[i].color
            canvas?.drawArc(mRectF, startAngle, sweepAngle, true, mPaint)
            startAngle += sweepAngle
        }

        if (isTouched) {
            mRectF = RectF(0F, 0F, width.toFloat() - unselectedConstant, height.toFloat() - unselectedConstant)
            mPaint.color = Color.RED
            canvas?.drawArc(mRectF, 0F, 45F, true, mPaint)
        }
        mPaint.color = Color.WHITE
        canvas?.drawArc(mRectFInner, 0F, 360F, true, mPaint)
    }

    fun setPieChartItems(itemList: ArrayList<PieChartItem>) {
        pieChartItemList = itemList
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        val w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
        val h = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        mCanvas = Canvas()
        mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            isTouched = true
            Log.e("ANKUSH", mBitmap?.getPixel(event.x.toInt(), event.y.toInt()).toString())
            invalidate()
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }
```

Comment: If you already had draw the archs you have the position of those and can compare with the values from onTouchListener

Comment: For a more complete answer add some functional code we can edit

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos added code

Comment: you could have list of arcs that you draw in a list instead of having one rect and just changing sweep angle. Then you on touch you could loop through the list of rect and check if the touch is within the rect and then you could do whatever you want by redrawing. This is just one idea.

Comment: @Raghunandan please provide sample code

Comment: @AnkushKapoor i had posted a link to one of your earlier questions see the blog where he draws squares using rect in the tictac toe application.

Answer (score 2):

Face same problem. Finally found a solution using this function for convert click coordinates to angle.

```
    private fun convertTouchEventPointToAngle(xPos: Float, yPos: Float): Double {
    var x = xPos - (width * 0.5f)
    val y = yPos - (height * 0.5f)

    var angle = Math.toDegrees(atan2(y.toDouble(), x.toDouble()) + Math.PI / 2)
    angle = if (angle < 0) angle + 360 else angle
    return angle
}
```

Found on article https://enginebai.com/2018/05/07/android-custom-view/ so might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the event and draw it accordling something like:

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    if (event?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        isTouched = true
        touchedAtX = event.x.toInt()
        touchedAtY = event.x.toInt()
        Log.e("ANKUSH", mBitmap?.getPixel(event.x.toInt(), event.y.toInt()).toString())
        invalidate()
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event)
}
```

And modify the onDraw

```
for (i in 0 until pieChartItemList.size) {
        sweepAngle = (pieChartItemList[i].percent * 3.6).toFloat()
        Log.e("ANKUSH - SweepAngle $i", sweepAngle.toString())
        mPaint.color = pieChartItemList[i].color
        canvas?.drawArc(mRectF, startAngle, sweepAngle, true, mPaint)
        startAngle += sweepAngle
        if (isTouched && mRectF.contains(touchedAtX, touchedAtY) {
            canvas?.drawArc(mRectF, startAngle - 15, sweepAngle + 15, true, mPaint)
        }
    }
```

Note that my code doesn't account for the startAngle and sweepAngle while doing collision detection, but you will need to know based on those which specific arch is touched by its coordinates.

Comment: mRectF.contains(touchedAtX, touchedAtY)

From this i can only get if the touched position is inside circle or not. How do I get which arc is touched? Please explain

Comment: thats the exactly the part you need to solve, it will be something just like with the parameters```(mRectF, startAngle, sweepAngle, true)``` the point I made here in the answer is that when you find the touched arch you can fire the event